# Chrome browser fails to launch in Appium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, appium

someone please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.
While running java code to open chrome browser in Emulator, I am getting "Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83" error message.

```
public class ChromeBrowserLaunch {
    AppiumDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {   
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "8.0");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
        driver.get("http://facebook.com");
        driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"m_login_email\"]").sendKeys("geeta");
        driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='m_login_password']").sendKeys("geeta");
        driver.hideKeyboard();
        driver.findElement(By.id("signup-button")).click();
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
>   remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
>   error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: A new session could not be created. Details:
>   session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
>   version 83
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>       System info: host: 'DESKTOP-R5U0RRK', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_231'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>       remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: A new session
>   could not be created. Details: session not created: This version of
>   ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
>           at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
>           at asyncHandler (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>       System info: host: 'DESKTOP-R5U0RRK', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_231'

Answer (score 1):

Chrome browser on Android has the package name `com.android.chrome` and the name of the activity `com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main`

In Appium you don't need a browser executable to open a browser like Selenium, so just add **`.APP_PACKAGE`** and **`.APP_ACTIVITY`** in your capability, like this:

```
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.chrome");
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
```

Following import:

```
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
```

Remove this line from your code:

```
cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

**Note**: Make sure the chrome browser is installed on the device.

Reference : [How to find appPackage and appActivity name of your App](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/)

Comment: It's helpful but getting another error, mentioned below. Can you pls suggest any answer.

Comment: @manish Try to add more seconds in : `.implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. Btw, you can edit your question, not post as answer. Click **`edit`** below the question.