# It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient,InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, testng, appium, appium-android

I am trying to open a url using appium, testng but getting an error. Following is my code:

```
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "7f4a75f0");
            // ,ce011821740e3c530c
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "10");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
            capabilities.setCapability("Emulator", "true");


            capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "/home/bhawneet/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver");
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078372/chrome-browser-fails-to-launch-in-appium-using-java/62085852#62085852

Comment: thanks @frianH , I am looking into it.